# Persistent Flashdata with Redis in Laravel

Tags: session, caching, laravel, laravel-4, redis

I'm using Redis as session driver in Laravel 4.2 stable.

Ever since this morning, after I've got a `composer update`, the flashdata in sessions are not self-destroying. They are persistent. But if I switch from `redis` to `file` session driver, they are working as they should.
These are the updated packages:

```
composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)         
  - Removing symfony/finder (v2.5.3)
  - Installing symfony/finder (v2.5.4)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Removing symfony/translation (v2.5.3)
  - Installing symfony/translation (v2.5.4)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Removing symfony/security-core (v2.5.3)
  - Installing symfony/security-core (v2.5.4)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Removing symfony/routing (v2.5.3)
  - Installing symfony/routing (v2.5.4)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Removing symfony/process (v2.5.3)
  - Installing symfony/process (v2.5.4)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Removing symfony/http-foundation (v2.5.3)
  - Installing symfony/http-foundation (v2.5.4)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Removing symfony/event-dispatcher (v2.5.3)
  - Installing symfony/event-dispatcher (v2.5.4)
    Loading from cache

  - Removing symfony/debug (v2.5.3)
  - Installing symfony/debug (v2.5.4)
    Loading from cache

  - Removing symfony/http-kernel (v2.5.3)
  - Installing symfony/http-kernel (v2.5.4)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Removing symfony/dom-crawler (v2.5.3)
  - Installing symfony/dom-crawler (v2.5.4)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Removing symfony/css-selector (v2.5.3)
  - Installing symfony/css-selector (v2.5.4)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Removing symfony/console (v2.5.3)
  - Installing symfony/console (v2.5.4)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Removing symfony/browser-kit (v2.5.3)
  - Installing symfony/browser-kit (v2.5.4)
    Loading from cache

  - Removing nesbot/carbon (1.11.0)
  - Installing nesbot/carbon (1.12.0)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Removing symfony/filesystem (v2.5.3)
  - Installing symfony/filesystem (v2.5.4)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Removing barryvdh/laravel-debugbar (v1.6.8)
  - Installing barryvdh/laravel-debugbar (v1.7.5)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Removing guzzlehttp/guzzle (4.2.1)
  - Installing guzzlehttp/guzzle (4.2.2)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Removing symfony/class-loader (v2.5.3)
  - Installing symfony/class-loader (v2.5.4)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Removing bkwld/croppa (dev-master 6882599)
  - Installing bkwld/croppa (dev-master f38d935)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Removing way/generators (dev-master 5edee3a)
  - Installing way/generators (dev-master 27a8d2e)
    Downloading: 100%         

Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
Generating optimized class loader
```

Everything was working okay until the last composer update.

Have anyone else have experienced this? If so, how can I fix this?

Note: changing the cache and session driver to file works as it should, but I need redis.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: May I ask why is this downvoted ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as a reference, It's fixed after a composer update days after. It was possibly a symfony component bug.